# TinyMCE show menubar on left

Tags: javascript, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

Is there a way to customize the menubar in latest version of TinyMCE on left side? I am unable to find any documentation on that specific part of the editor. The 2nd image below demonstrates the part I'm specifing.

Current UI:
[image]

I want the left menu as below:
[image]